# RegularExpression to detect below text format: @<10|asdffdfs>@

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I need to write a regular expression to replace string `@<Number|Text>@` to `Text` in my `iOS` application.

`@<Number|Text>@`

e.g.

- `@<12|abcd>@` will be `abcd`
- `@<1|I am a good boy>>>>>@` will be `I am a good boy>>>>`
- `@<a|abcd>@` no change, because the first part is not numeric
- `@<0|god bless me@>>@` will be `god bless me@>`
- `@<01212|I love you!>@ Do you love me? @<0222| No, I love your sister>@` will be `I love you! Do you love me?  No, I love your sister`

I am not familiar with regular expression, can someone help me?

What I have tried:
`@<(\d{1,})\|([\S]+)>@`
`@<(\d{1,})\|([\S\s]+)>@`

P.S. Any other solution is welcome. Actually what I want to do is replace `@<ID|NAME>@` to `@NAME` and make `@NAME` as clickable(I use `TTTAttributedLabel`), the url will be `goto://ID`

Comment: You need to research and try something, then add your attempt to the question if it doesn't work and explain what it does wrong

Comment: @Wain thanks, I actually tried something like: "@<(\d{1,})\|([\S ]+)>@", but failed.

Comment: why has it to be a RegEx-based solution? A parser based on NSScanner could be easily coded and performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression you are searching for is `@<\\d+\\|(.*?)>@`. And the replacement template is `$1`.

Breaking down the regular expression:

- `@<` will match the prefix of the expression
- `\\d+` will match at least one digit
- `\\|` will match the `|` character
- (.*?) will match any character up to the next part of the regular expression (`>@`); the parentheses create a sub-pattern, which gets mapped to `$1` in the replacement string
- finally, `>@` will match the end of the pattern

The `?` addresses the greediness of the `*`quantifier, without it `*` would not work for the last example, as it will match anything between the first `@<` and the last `>@`.

Comment: Or this one should be even more efficient: `@<[0-9]+[|]([^>]*(?:>(?!@)[^>]*)*)>@`. Or even `@<[0-9]+[|]([^>]*(?:>[^@]*)*)>@`.